# How do i make the calculation as 1 day when subtracting same two dates

Tags: python, date, django-views

Here is my code for calculating the difference between two given dates

```
days = datetime.strptime(todate, "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(fromdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
print days
```

It works fine. However, the problem is when given two same dates i.e `todate = 2015-07-31, fromdate = 2015-07-31`, it calculates it as 0 days. I want that if the `todate` and `fromdate` is same the calculation should be 1 not 0.

Comment: It is the correct behaviour. If you want 1, it is better to handle it after the difference calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `max` to limit return value is not lower than a day.

```
days = max(timedelta(days=1),
           datetime.strptime(todate, "%Y-%m-%d") -
           datetime.strptime(fromdate, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

---

```
>>> fromdate = '2015-07-31'
>>> todate = '2015-07-31'
>>> days = max(timedelta(days=1),
...            datetime.strptime(todate, "%Y-%m-%d") -
...            datetime.strptime(fromdate, "%Y-%m-%d"))
>>> days
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Comment: @DhruvinSoni, Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are people who have tried to answer your question. If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) that was most useful for you.

Comment: ohh okay! Sorry a novice :)

Comment: @DhruvinSoni, No problem. Happy programming.

Comment: i have encountered one more problem, need some help.
When calculating from 2015-08-05 to 2015-08-06 it counts as 1 day, i want that to be calculated as 2 days. Help!

Comment: @DhruvinSoni, Maybe you want this: `max(timedelta(days=1), datetime.strptime(...) - datetime.strptime(...) + timedelta(days=1))`

Comment: yeah, i exactly needed this. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using boolean operator maybe:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

days = datetime.strptime(todate, "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(fromdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
days = days or timedelta(days=1)
```